# Xcode error "file not found" after git rebase

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, git

Just re-based the repository Xcode project to an older version that used to work fine. (in an attempt to add back support for iOS 7)

Now - one of the frameworks is through a "file not found" error for the header files. But, the files are still there. Everything used to build just fine on this version of the project (3-4 months ago), everything builds fine on current, new version of the repo. So, why the trouble here?

Comment: i think you mean revert back, rebasing is something different in git (just to be pedantic)

Comment: also did you try clean the project after? (also delete derived data)

Comment: @Fonix ha ok. I've tried cleaning it. I'll try deleting derived data now.. haven't tried that yet

Comment: if all else fails, why not just delete and re-add the library, could be faster than trying to find the cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rebasing** is a concept where in you change the entire history of your commits. You should only rebase a branch onto its parent branch or it might create issues.

Rebasing repositions the head and then applies all commits made after the point of branching as patches, one patch at a time. Each patch is applied and resolved for conflicts if any. You must do this until all patches are applied. If you are not careful in this process, its easy to accidentally lose code or entire files or frameworks that you have added.
Please go through the [git rebase documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) for more details.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I have found that git rebase can be a bit of a nightmare when using XCode. From my experience, the best solution to making sure a branch is up-to-date with master is by doing the following (instead of rebasing):

While on your branch you created off master:

Select Source Control on the XCode Navigation Bar -> Pull -> Pull remote changes, select "origin/master" and select "Pull"

I've had the most success doing things this way vs. the pain of fixing a rebase gone wild.

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps hope this will help you.

1)target of project -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources ->

2)delete the [found filename that cause the error in program].m

3)Add it back again in you project.

4)Clean Your iOS project And then Build Again.